# How to protect Patio door from rain

Tags: waterproofing, patio, water-damage

Have a rental property and this house has patio on backside. There is no canopy or awing over my patio door. It been getting damaged at the bottom due to rain.

How to protect this patio door from rain?

Any help in suggestions?
[image]
[image]

Comment: You said it yourself: "canopy or awning".

Comment: "Best?" is subjective, and "Can I?" is too broad. Please revise to ask something clear, specific, and objective.

Comment: "have a rental property" Is this a property you own and are renting _to_ others, or is this a property you're renting _from_ someone else? Your statement isn't particularly clear.

Comment: @FreeMan- when I am asking or mentioning I have rental property so definitely I am asking in the context only. I think you making it more complicated than and trying to distracting other people thought if they want to answer. It seems you are more experienced so you should understand the problem as quick as possible.

Comment: @FreeMan - how the problem solution varies on your question. Doesn’t matter it’s 1st or 2nd. If it please explain. May be I am wrong . Will try to ask in better way next time. Bye the way. Its first option to answer of your question

Comment: If you're renting from someone else, there's a limit to what physical changes you can make to the property without getting permission from the landlord. You wouldn't want your tenant making these changes without contacting you, right?

Comment: @FreeMan- please go Google or ask someone . What does mean “I have rental property’ and is landlord use to say or tenant. When i was tenant  I never said I have rental property. So if you don’t know you should not ask and  demotivate the people who come for help here, I find many people just comment for increasing their number of post. I am sorry to say all this truth. If this is plateform for help needy people, try to help them if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a full porch roof you won't keep splash from dampening that wooden frame. That's why most such doors are wrapped with vinyl or aluminum these days.

I'd consider having a siding company wrap the jamb and mullion for you, then caulk it at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks . If that wood bar is replaceable ?

Comment: Also the door is metal but the trim around and the middle bar is wood . Is there sort of strip that I can wrap around the middle wood ?

Comment: _Anything_ is replaceable. It's a matter of will. Are you willing to disassemble the entire door to remove the fasteners that likely come in from top and bottom? I already described the "strip" I'd use. Putting wood over wood doesn't help you.

Comment: I can build or fix anything. But sometimes we need experienced people sometime to solve even a small issue :)